# Handle JSON variable dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, json

Hello I have JSON like this :

```
simples: {
   EA201SPACC25ANID-126276: {},
   GF867HDKLI25ANID-126309: {},
   RT211YUIAD912IDO-126310: {},
},
```

The variable's name always different. How can we declare the model for C# class? BTW, I am using JSON.NET

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If your Json structure will keep the same over time

Since you cannot have a property like `EA201SPACC25ANID-126276`, the easiest way here would be:

```
public class MyCustomModel
{
    [JsonProperty("EA201SPACC25ANID-126276")]
    public string Something_1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GF867HDKLI25ANID-126309")]
    public string Something_2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RT211YUIAD912IDO-126310")]
    public string Something_3 { get; set; }
}
```

Than you just deserialize the object:

```
JsonConver.DeserializeObject<MyCustomModel>(myJsonString);
```

#### If your Json properties will change over time (other names)

If this is your case, you can choose either to receive a dictionary or to bind it manually. For basic scenarios, the first option should work fine:

```
public ActionResult(Dictionary<string, string> model)
```

But this approach fails on complex object bindings. To avoid this you can create a custom model binder, like:

```
public class MyCustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(var item in request.QueryString.Keys.Cast<string>())
        {
            // You might want to cast your data into appropriate types...
            dictionary.Add(item, request.QueryString[item]);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

And on your controller, use:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomBinder))] Dictionary<string, object> model)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. The variable's name always different.

Comment: You can either use dynamic or create a new model binder. Dynamic library requires .NET 4. Check edit for an idea.

Comment: Ok, I am still trying to implement it

Comment: Now that you've said that the name of properties will change over time and considering the `-` on the property names, I think that the best option is to use the two last cases. Either map directly into a `Dictionary<string, string>` (work on basic cases) or create a binder for complex cases where you have a property with multiple properties and all. If that's the case, custom bind to `Dictionary<string, object>`